# How to create shortcut in Total Commander to remove read only attribute

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, read-only, total-commander

How can I create a keyboard shortcut for Total commander, which will remove read only or any other attribute from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expecting you know which attribute you want to modify, the next step will be to find a shortcut to be used. You may look for [Total Commander shortcuts](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Total-Commander_8.html) to modify the one you don't use that often or suits you the most.

In example below I will use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to create shortcut for removing **Read Only** attribute:

1. Click *"Configuration"*-> *"Options..."* -> *"Misc"*.
2. In *"Redifine hotkeys (Keyboard remapping)"* mark *Ctrl* and select *P*.
3. Click on the magnifying glass next to *"Command"*.
4. Go to the bottom of the list and click on *usercmd.ini*
5. Click on *"New"* and name the new command for example *em_RemoveReadOnly*
6. Fill out the dialog like this:

   - Command: attrib.exe -R
   - Parameters: %P%N
   - Tooltip: Mark file readonly
   - Check the box *"Run minimized*"
   - Icons are optional

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

-R parameter in command removes Read Only attribute, the + sign do the opposite (adding the attribute). Similar for Archive[A], System[S] and Hidden[H]

Resources:
[attrib.exe function and its parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html)
[forum post driving this question](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=40179&view=next)